# How to use OpenCV with camera on Jetson Nano with Yocto/poky

Tags: python, opencv, yocto, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I've created a minimal xfce image with Yocto/poky on a Jetson Nano using warrior branches (poky warrior, meta-tegra warrior-l4t-r32.2, openembedded warrior) and CUDA 10.

Image boots and runs perfectly, and the camera test:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3820, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=960, height=616' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e
```

works like a charm.

Now I would like to use OpenCV on the camera feed, but I can't get it to work.

I've added these packages to `IMAGE_INSTALL`:

```
...
opencv \
libopencv-core \
libopencv-imgproc \
opencv-samples \
gstreamer1.0-omx-tegra \
python3 \
python3-modules \
python3-dev \
python-numpy \
...
```

To get the OpenCV installed. When I run /usr/bin/opencv_version, it returns version 3.4.5, python version is 3.7.2 and GCC version is 7.2.1.

When I try to run [this OpenCV test code](https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/CSI-Camera/blob/master/face_detect.py) it returns

```
[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(createGStreamerCapture(filename)): trying ...

(python3.7:5163): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: ..._: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(createGStreamerCapture(filename)): result=(nil) isOpened=-1 ...

Unable to open camera
```

I've tried looking around online for solutions but they don't seem to work.

EDIT:
There does appear to be a problem with using CAP_GSTREAMER in the VideoCapture function as running the same program with CAP_FFMPEG instead works just fine on an mp4 video.

Using `cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0", CAP_FFMPEG)` just returns with isOpen=-1. How do I get the camera to open in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pipeline that you said works for you:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3820, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=960, height=616' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e
```

This is the pipeline that is mentioned in the script:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3280, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw, width=820, height=616, format=BGRx' ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink
```

The difference between working and nonworking pipelines is the addition of `videoconvert` and `appsink`
The error `GStreamer-CRITICAL **: ..._: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed` indicates there is some GStreamer element missing from your system. You can try adding the missing plugins by adding the following package group to your image:

```
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
```

Alternatively, you can replace the pipeline in `face_detect.py` with your working pipeline, but keep in mind that the script probably needs the video converted to BGR before feeding it to `appsink` for the algorithm to work. You might need to look up documentation for the `nvidconv` element to see if this is supported.

EDIT: Judging by your comment, you may have been missing `gstreamer1.0-python` as well.

Comment: When I try to run ```bitbake gstreamer1.0-plugin-base``` it says it is already build and so must be part of the image. And I've also tried taking the pipeline that works and replace the face_detect.py pipeline, but still the same error... This is a really frustrating problem as I know both camera and OpenCV works - just not together at the moment.

Comment: When I try to run ```gst-launch-1.0 -v nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3280, height=2464, framerate=21/1, fflip?methodormat=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw, width=820, height=616, format=BGRx' ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink``` It returns `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "videoconvert"`

Comment: I guess i'm missing some dependencies or something? I just don't have the slightest idea how or what is needed at this point

Comment: @MichaelChristensen Running `bitbake <recipe>` and showing no new tasks have been built does not mean it is part of an image. It may mean that some other dependency caused it to be built. Try adding the mentioned recipe to your image or via appending to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in `local.conf` to be certain.

Comment: @MichaelChristensen, The no element `videoconvert` confirms that base Gstreamer plugins do not exist on your board. Please add `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base` to the image as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I did but same error, that's why I tried adding all the other stuff. I deleted my "answer" anyway, but you think maybe the other gstream packages: 
```gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \ gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \ gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \ gstreamer1.0-python \ ```
Could have some impact on it working?

Comment: @MichaelChristensen It really depends on your pipeline. That's why I asked in my deleted comment to see the output of "-v" (If OK, you can try uploading to pastebin). As a side tip, you can also invoke `gst-inspect-1.0` on plugins. From eyeballing your pipeline, my guess is that you need `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base`, `gstreamer1.0-omx-tegra` and `gstreamer1.0-python`.  The rest is unnecessary, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following gstreamer pipeline:

stream = 'nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=%d, height=%d, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 !nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! appsink' % (1280, 720, 30,0, 640, 480)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream,cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

This will solve the problem